# The log out issue in Salesforce mobile SDK android - Hybrid

Tags: android, sfdcmobilesdk-android, salesforce-sdk-android

When we log out, redirected to login page, in that login page if we login again redirected to login page again. If we close and open the app again, logins with out asking for password

```
{
    "remoteAccessConsumerKey": "3MVG9Gmy2zmPB01olNAGj.l0Jw6fK3H_ckds02fHDSd_oFbMhyizYE3nuJli2m31GrJ69tkIL_vtPYFhs",
    "oauthRedirectURI": "https://XXXXXXXXXXX/services/oauth2/success",
    "oauthScopes": ["web", "api", "refresh_token"],
    "isLocal": false,
    "startPage": "/one/one.app",
    "errorPage": "error.html",
    "shouldAuthenticate": true,
    "attemptOfflineLoad": false,
    "androidPushNotificationClientId": "731453457605"
}
```

in servers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<servers>
    <server name="Community Login" url="https://url_to_salesforce_community"/>
</servers>
```